# Give an example of a subset $L'$ of a lattice $L$ , such that $L'$ is a lattice but not a sublattice of $L$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

Find the   example of a subset $L'$ of a lattice $L$ , such that $L'$ is a lattice but not a sublattice of $L$.

Comment: What is a lattice? What is a sublattice?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. Lattices are a standard mathematical notion: see [Lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) on wikipedia, where the definition of a sublattice is also given. Thus the question is clear and makes perfect sense. I vote for reopening this question.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin so standard  there is even [more than one standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group))   Now, one could infer what is meant from the tag but anyway the question is not detailed enough even if I think I know what is meant. OP should read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question and [edit] the question accordingly. You prematurely voting to reopen is rather unhelpful.

Comment: @quid I disagree with that argument. There's a lattice-orders tag included, so of course we are talking about lattices as algebraic structures coming from a partial order with sups and infs of two point sets.

Comment: @Jakobian  as I said more than half a decade ago  "one could infer what is meant from the tag but anyway the question is not detailed enough even if I think I know what is meant"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a 2x2 lattice with elements 0, a, b, c.  Add a new top, 1.  Now delete c.  The resulting subset is a lattice.  If it were a sublattice, then the join of a and b would have to be c (but it's 1).

The point is, sublattices are subsets that are closed under the (over)lattice's operations.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can order-embed either the pentagon $\mathbf{N}_5$ or the diamond $\mathbf{M}_3$ in the 8 element boolean lattice, the cube $\mathbf{2}^3$.
However, this one is distributive and those are not, so they're not sublattices of the cube.

Comment: And of course every poset, in particular every lattice, is order-embeddable in a Boolean lattice.